# localStorage not accessible in IOS-6 Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

I am not able to access localStorage in Safari (IPad with IOS-6).

For example, the following code is working fine in Windows on all browsers and on (iPad with iOS-5) but not in iOS-6:

```
localStorage.setItem("var","5");
alert(localStorage.getItem("var"));
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error? Is `window.localStorage` defined? [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) confirms web storage is supported by iOS Safari.

Comment: The error which i got was : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 localStorage doesn't works in ios safari private browsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-doesnt-works-in-ios-safari-private-browsing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by turning off private browsing on the iPad. I came across the solution from the reference : https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/312#issuecomment-2994845

Comment: What's the best way to deal with this issue as a developer? It seems like localStorage can't be relied on in Safari at all.