# Reliable method for persistent storage in HTML5 hybrid app on iOS/Android

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I, like many others, am building an iOS and Android Hybrid App with HTML5/Javascript and a bridge (Phonegap/Intel XDK). I have yet to find a definitive answer on persistent storage, e.g. storing app settings for the lifetime of the app.

Posts like: [is localStorage on iPad Safari guaranteed to be persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114571/is-localstorage-on-ipad-safari-guaranteed-to-be-persistent) suggest there is no guarantee that settings stored will persist.

Can anyone put my mind at rest and give a decent answer as to whether it's possible? A lot of useful apps are potentially useless without the ability to store user entered data.

I have played with lawnchair.js http://brian.io/lawnchair/ and am heading down this route. Can anyone too suggest whether this solves the problem or suggest the best persistent storage option in their opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is rather reliable method. This data removes only when user removes app from his device.
You can also save data with [WebSQL DB](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) for Android devices. But it's rather uncomfortably.
Or you can use [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) to save settings in folder, like .yourapp, and read data from this file. But user can remove this folder.
So I recommend localStorage.