# What is data persistence status on iOS 16.6 and latest safari?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, persistence

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795409/is-indexeddb-on-safari-guaranteed-to-be-persistent) answers are obsolete for latest iOS and Safari versions, does have anyone conducted a tests or investigation of how it is now?

As stated [here](https://firt.dev/notes/pwa-ios/#high-level-overview-of-web-abilities-for-pwas), the "Storage Management: Persistent" should be supported from version 15.2.

Does it mean the eviction policy (7+ days of unused) would not hit data stored with flag persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PWA are not affected by the 7days of unused rule.
I have no issue storing datas in Indexeddb for months in my PWA, both on iOS and Android.