# Mobile browser localStorage doesn't seem to be 100% persistent

Tags: ios, angular, mobile-safari

I'm seeing what appears to be an iOS Safari issue that the localStorage is being removed without request

Googling around has brought up some issues with using localStorage, such as iOS removing browser storage if the device is low on memory

EG - [is localStorage on iPad Safari guaranteed to be persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114571/is-localstorage-on-ipad-safari-guaranteed-to-be-persistent)

What is a reliable and persistent method I can use to store a JWT in a users browser?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using cookies to store jwt tokens.
check [this article](https://tkacz.pro/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens/) for explanation.

Edit: typo

Answer (score 0):

This is the Apple way...

> Starting in iOS 13.4 and Safari 13.1, LocalStorage will be cleared after 7 days of no user interaction on a site.

See **7-Day Cap on All Script-Writeable Storage** at [this webkit blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/)